# How to show a placeholder image until the secondary image is loaded

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I want to show second image when hover the first image 
The second image path is in `data-alt-src`

With this function i am swap the src of the img tag to show the second image

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = jqr(this); 
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');

    if (newSource != ''){
        $this.css("background-image",$this.attr('src'));
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.stop(true, true).css("opacity",".5").attr('src', newSource).animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 1000);

    }

}
```

But some times the second image take time to load, So when user hovers the fist image the second image will appear broken.

I am using jquery lazy load form loading the images.Loader is showing for the first image. How to show the loader for the second image as well

Answer (score 2):

Try to load second image to browser's cache using `new Image()` and swap images in image's `load` event:

```
/* var $this = $(this), ... */
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){/*...*/ $this.attr('src', newSource); /*...*/};
img.src = newSource;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I have lots of images loading at a time, It is actually a grid. And number of items in the grid varies all the time. Can u brief a little on how to do that

Comment: I meant to change your `sourceSwap` function to
    var sourceSwap=function(){
        var $this=jqr(this),
            newSource=$this.data('alt-src');
        if(newSource!=''){
            var img=new Image();
            img.onload=function(){
                $this.css('background-image',$this.attr('src'))
                    .data('alt-src',$this.attr('src'));
                    .stop(true,true)
                    .css('opacity','.5')
                    .attr('src',newSource)
                    .animate({opacity:1},1000);
            };
            img.src=newSource;
        }
    }

Comment: This solved my issue of broken images. But i found a new thing. for some images once the second image comes on hover then the first image will not come back when cursor is moved out from second image.

Comment: Could you create test example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: The problem i am facing here is this happens only when there is lots of images. may a 30 item grids. So if i create sample html files it is loading fine. So unable to replicate this in an html. And one more thing here if it gives more clarity to the situation is i am using lazy load plugin for showing the first image.